# how to select a form inside a datatables without an id

Tags: jquery, laravel, forms, datatables, laravelcollective

Ive this form write inside a table with html laravel collective:

```
 @foreach($patients as $patient)
            <tr>
                {{Form::open(['route' => 'patientDetails'])}}
                {{Form::hidden('patient',json_encode($patient))}}
                {{Form::close()}}
                <td>{{$patient['display']}}</td>
                .......
                </td>
                </a>
            </tr>           
        @endforeach

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
```

Then i wrote this script part, thats would lets the user to a new page when he hits a row of the table, with the data presente on hidden form.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#patients').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        fixedColumns:   true,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: "_all",
                className: 'dt-body-center'
            }
        ]
    });
    var table = $('#patients').DataTable();
    $('#patients tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        if (window.confirm( 'Stai per accedere ai dettagli di: '+data[0]+'' )) {
         //here I need a way to select the form inside the row just cliked
            console.log(data); //this do not contains the hidden form
        };});});
```

maybe ive mixed too many concept and there is an easy way to accieve the same goal ( click on a row of this table and go to a next page with some additional data via post method) but actually id like to find a way to select the form inside the row via jquery and then doing a submit.

Comment: so, let me know if I'm right: what you want is to submit the form when the user clicks the row that contains it? also: what do you mean by *new page*? new tab or same tab?

Comment: @Scaramouche you are right, and the user should let to a new page in the same tab, after hit the confirmetion button on js "window.confirm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in this example there are two rows, each with a form in their first TD. All you have to do is attach the handler to each TR and use jQuery's selectors to find the form inside that TR. Finally you just invoke [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) on it.

I hope the idea helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    const table = $('#patients').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        fixedColumns:   true,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: "_all",
                className: 'dt-body-center'
            }
        ]
    });
    
    table.on('click', 'tr', function () {
        const form = $(this).find('form').first();
        if (window.confirm( 'Stai per accedere ai dettagli di: '+form.attr('action')+'' )){
         //here I need a way to select the form inside the row just cliked
          //  console.log(data); //this do not contains the hidden form
        
          form.submit()
        };
    });
        
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="patients" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Form</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>
                <form method='get' action='https://google.com'>
                  
                  <input type='submit' value='GOOGLE'/>
                </form>
                </td>

                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <form method='get' action='https://wikipedia.com'>
                  <input type='submit' value='WIKIPEDIA'/>
                </form>
                </td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
           </table>
```

Comment: i just use the "constant" part, and it works! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use classes so you have an easier time with jquery selectors

```xml
<tbody>
    @foreach ($patients as $patient)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $patient['display'] }}</td>
        <td>
            <form class="table-form" action="..." method="...">
                <input class="table-hidden" type="hidden" value='@json($patient)' name="patient">
                <button type="submit">View</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

```js
$(() => {
    let table = $('#patients').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        fixedColumns: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: "_all",
                className: 'dt-body-center'
            }
        ]
    });

    $('.table-form').on('submit', e => {
        let patient = JSON.parse($(this).find('.table-hidden').val());

        if(window.confirm(`Stai per accedere ai dettagli di: ${patient[0]}`) {
            // console.log(patient);
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: here there is an explicict button to hit and perform the submission, thats not my goal, id like to click on row (as the first part the function that ive wrote did) and then after confirm let the user to another page... but i think that i can use your logic to add some usefull class, thanks

Comment: i've tried to add an unique id on the form, and to catch it with '               var form = document.getElementsByTagName(riga);' but the form seem to be not "submitable'